# laravel parent child relationship with three tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

i am new to Laravel i need help in building a relation with models, i have **coach model** **which has many clients and client belong to Coach** and i can perform operation on clients like this **Auth()->user()->clients()->create($request->all());** now i want to add courses in way that i could use something like **Auth()->user()->clients()->courses()->create($request->all());** how should i make a relation for this. what will be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't do `->clients()->courses()` because the `->clients()` will returns you a lot clients of user so `->courses()` doesnt know the course of which client do you want to get. 
You can create a relationship between the Couch and Course(add couche_id to courses table) model so then you can do
`Auth()->user()->courses()->create($request->all());`